# Input Decorator not showing data from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am Trying to display data from parent component to child component. My parent component is TableOverviewComponent and child component is TableComponent. codes are given below. I am not getting any error, but it's now showing message from parent component to child component

**table .component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  public message: string = "hello world"
  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

**table.component.html**

```
<app-table-overview
  [message]= "message" 
></app-table-overview>
```

**table-overview.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as c3 from 'c3';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-overview',
  templateUrl: './table-overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-overview.component.css']
})
export class TableOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message: string
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**table-overview.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h3>Child</h3>
  say {{message}}
</div>
```

Comment: try `@Input('message') message: string` in your table-overview component.

Comment: didn't work        ...................

Comment: The code looks correct and should work. Try to reproduce at https://stackblitz.com

Comment: The way you have it should work, but you can try to interpolate differently:
 `<app-table-overview message= "{{message}}" ></app-table-overview>`

Comment: Both hints provided by @Bradd are unnecessary at best, and make the code worse.

Comment: Why don't you try implementing ``ngOnChanges()`` ?